# Failure to edit div on nav click event

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I typed up most of the pertinent information into the code itself
I would love a explanation of whats happening and why, especially between the multiple outcomes of .text .html and not returning what i want

```
<DOCTYPE! Html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
p{color: white;
background: black;}
</style>
<script>  
$('document').ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=$(this).html;
            });
}); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
This is a test html to trouble shoot the functionality of the script, the above script runs and does what it needs to in other aspects but when trying to add in the ability to edit a divs text based on the nav clicked on theres a error.

when using ".text" in the script i get <p> function (a){return V(this,function(a){return void 0===a?m.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||y).createTextNode(a))},null,a,arguments.length)} </p> in my div,when i use ".html" in my script i get  <p> function (a){return V(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a)return 1===b.nodeType?b.innerHTML.replace(fb,""):void 0;if(!("string"!=typeof a||mb.test(a)||!k.htmlSerialize&&gb.test(a)||!k.leadingWhitespace&&hb.test(a)||rb[(jb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){a=a.replace(ib,"<$1>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(m.cleanData(ub(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)} </p>


<ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a href="#"> This is the text that should be placed in the div </a></li>
</ul>

<div id="text"> this text should be changed </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery method `.html()` is a function you need to call it / use `()`. Or go vanilla and just do `this.innerHTML`.

That means:

```
$(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
});
```

### Example in the snippet:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;
            });
});
```

```css
p{color: white;
background: black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is a test html to trouble shoot the functionality of the script, the above script runs and does what it needs to in other aspects but when trying to add in the ability to edit a divs text based on the nav clicked on theres a error.

when using ".text" in the script i get <p> function (a){return V(this,function(a){return void 0===a?m.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||y).createTextNode(a))},null,a,arguments.length)} </p> in my div,when i use ".html" in my script i get  <p> function (a){return V(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a)return 1===b.nodeType?b.innerHTML.replace(fb,""):void 0;if(!("string"!=typeof a||mb.test(a)||!k.htmlSerialize&&gb.test(a)||!k.leadingWhitespace&&hb.test(a)||rb[(jb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){a=a.replace(ib,"<$1>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(m.cleanData(ub(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)} </p>


<ul id="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a href="#"> This is the text that should be placed in the div </a></li>
</ul>

<div id="text"> this text should be changed </div>
```

Comment: Ah see from a previous thing I was working on I was suggestedto not use innerHTML or text and just use html. By using innerHTML it works but returns undefined, when changing $(this) to just this,  it works perfectly

Comment: I appreciate the explanation at the top, I much rather learn why something is wrong then just substituing someones working code in for my own. Ive never used innerHTML as a function before, only ever used it to change data within something. The simple things always get me, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav").on('click', function() {
       $("#text").html( $(this).html() ); // Getting too nested here 
    }

}
```

Comment: "not use $(document) at all" why? What is wrong with delegation? You don't know if more `.nav` will be added. And vanilla JS/getElementById is good, you don't need to use jQuery for everything...

Comment: Just a preference. Plus, what difference will it make if you use delegation and more '.nav' elements are added? Won't the event handle be attached to the new elements too?

Comment: No, if you use `$('.nav')` only the `.nav` elements present at DOMReady will get a event handler attached.

Comment: But the code above is executed as a callback to $(document).ready(), so it will attach the event handler to all .nav events?

Comment: All nav events present at the moment. If more are added after they will not get a event handler attached. The event handler will not be attached to new elements created/inserted after DOMReady.

Comment: A delegated event handler will attach itself to newly inserted elements automatically?

Comment: If you use `$(document).on('click', '.nav', function() {` the delegated event will work on elements added after DOMReady, if you use `$('.nav').on('click', function() {` then nothing will happen when you click on a `.nav` element that was added after that piece of code was read/parsed.

Comment: I thought it was too good to be true. Anyway, OP used a delegated event as a callback to $(document).ready(), so it was redundant. Let me edit my code ...